# Ubuntu froze during 'sudo apt upgrade'

Tags: apt

My computer froze after I ran sudo apt update/upgrade.
I forcibly turned it off/on.
Is there anything I need to do to ensure everything is ok?
If I run sudo apt upgrade, I get a message that some packages have been kept back. I am not sure if that is related to the freeze during upgrading.

```
joe@Ubuntu-Desktop-SDA:~$ sudo apt update

[sudo] password for joe:

Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease

Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                

Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                                    

Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                              

Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                    

Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]                                                                

Hit:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_19.x jammy InRelease                                                                                  

Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [20.1 kB]                                                

Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [94.9 kB]                                              

Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [13.2 kB]

Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [254 kB]          

Hit:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu jammy InRelease

Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]        

Hit:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy InRelease            

Fetched 708 kB in 2s (446 kB/s)                                

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

26 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

joe@Ubuntu-Desktop-SDA:~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

Calculating upgrade... Done

Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free personal subscription on up to 5 machines.

Learn more at https://ubuntu.com/pro

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-50-generic

The following packages have been kept back:

  alsa-ucm-conf grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed snapd

The following packages will be upgraded:

  libnvidia-cfg1-515 libnvidia-compute-515 libnvidia-compute-515:i386 libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-decode-515:i386 libnvidia-encode-515

  libnvidia-encode-515:i386 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 libnvidia-gl-515 libnvidia-gl-515:i386

  linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-52-generic linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-52-generic

  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-52-generic nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-kernel-common-515 nvidia-kernel-source-515

  nvidia-utils-515 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515

22 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

4 standard LTS security updates

Need to get 424 MB of archives.

After this operation, 184 kB disk space will be freed.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-driver-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [468 kB]

Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-gl-515 i386 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [26.1 MB]

Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-gl-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [189 MB]

Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04 amd64 5.15.0-52.58+1 [5,384 B]

Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-52-generic amd64 5.15.0-52.58+1 [7,040 B]

Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-52-generic amd64 5.15.0-52.58+1 [39.7 kB]

Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-52-generic amd64 5.15.0-52.58+1 [42.8 MB]

Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-kernel-common-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [25.2 MB]

Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-kernel-source-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [31.3 MB]

Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-decode-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [1,450 kB]

Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-decode-515 i386 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [1,670 kB]

Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-compute-515 i386 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [54.2 MB]

Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-compute-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [49.9 MB]

Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-extra-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [62.0 kB]

Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-compute-utils-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [115 kB]

Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-encode-515 i386 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [50.2 kB]

Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-encode-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [46.2 kB]

Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-utils-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [367 kB]

Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [1,485 kB]

Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-fbc1-515 i386 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [56.9 kB]

Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-fbc1-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [51.8 kB]

Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-cfg1-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [95.1 kB]

Fetched 424 MB in 1min 23s (5,098 kB/s)                                                                                                      

Preconfiguring packages ...

(Reading database ... 205695 files and directories currently installed.)

Removing linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56+1) ...

linux-image-nvidia-5.15.0-50-generic: removing .ko files

(Reading database ... 205692 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../00-nvidia-driver-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking nvidia-driver-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../01-libnvidia-gl-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

De-configuring libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), to allow configuration of libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

dpkg-query: no packages found matching libnvidia-gl-510

Unpacking libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../02-libnvidia-gl-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...

dpkg-query: no packages found matching libnvidia-gl-510

Unpacking libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../03-linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04_5.15.0-52.58+1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04 (5.15.0-52.58+1) over (5.15.0-52.58) ...

Preparing to unpack .../04-linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-52-generic_5.15.0-52.58+1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-52-generic (5.15.0-52.58+1) over (5.15.0-52.58) ...

Preparing to unpack .../05-linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-52-generic_5.15.0-52.58+1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-52-generic (5.15.0-52.58+1) over (5.15.0-52.58) ...

Preparing to unpack .../06-linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-52-generic_5.15.0-52.58+1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-52-generic (5.15.0-52.58+1) over (5.15.0-52.58) ...

Preparing to unpack .../07-nvidia-kernel-common-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking nvidia-kernel-common-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../08-nvidia-kernel-source-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking nvidia-kernel-source-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../09-libnvidia-decode-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...

De-configuring libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), to allow configuration of libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04

.1) ...

Unpacking libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../10-libnvidia-decode-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../11-libnvidia-compute-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

De-configuring libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), to allow configuration of libnvidia-compute-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.

04.1) ...

Unpacking libnvidia-compute-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../12-libnvidia-compute-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...

Unpacking libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../13-libnvidia-extra-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../14-nvidia-compute-utils-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking nvidia-compute-utils-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../15-libnvidia-encode-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

De-configuring libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), to allow configuration of libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04

.1) ...

Unpacking libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../16-libnvidia-encode-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...

Unpacking libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../17-nvidia-utils-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking nvidia-utils-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../18-xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../19-libnvidia-fbc1-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

De-configuring libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), to allow configuration of libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)

...

Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../20-libnvidia-fbc1-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...

Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Preparing to unpack .../21-libnvidia-cfg1-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (515.76-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-compute-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up nvidia-kernel-common-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)

Setting up nvidia-kernel-source-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-52-generic (5.15.0-52.58+1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up nvidia-utils-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up nvidia-compute-utils-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-52-generic (5.15.0-52.58+1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Setting up linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-52-generic (5.15.0-52.58+1) ...

linux-image-nvidia-5.15.0-52-generic: constructing .ko files

nvidia-drm.ko: OK

nvidia-modeset.ko: OK

nvidia-peermem.ko: OK

nvidia-uvm.ko: OK

nvidia.ko: OK

Setting up linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04 (5.15.0-52.58+1) ...

Setting up nvidia-driver-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...

Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...

Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...

Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) ...

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic

Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic (5.15.0-52.58) ...

/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic

/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:

Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'

Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'

Generating grub configuration file ...

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-50-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic

Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting

Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.

Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.

Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sda2

Found Arch Linux on /dev/sda4

Warning: Please don't use old title `Arch Linux (on /dev/sda4)' for GRUB_DEFAULT, use `Advanced options for Arch Linux (on /dev/sda4)>Arch Linu

x (on /dev/sda4)' (for versions before 2.00) or `gnulinux-advanced-ef0fcb2d-79ed-40f4-a6f4-1bcdee440b75>gnulinux---ef0fcb2d-79ed-40f4-a6f4-1bcd

ee440b75' (for 2.00 or later)

Found CentOS Linux 7 (Core) on /dev/sda5

Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

done
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, and post the full message if there are any errors.

Comment: I'd avoid using the power to force a system off; were you unable to use commands to cause it to reboot? or at worst using SysRq commands direct to the kernel (*don't forget Ubuntu uses Linux thus you can use Linux features!*).  The force power-off can cause problems and should be avoided (*if you were unable to use SysRq you should mention as that's useful diagnostic detail*).  Either way you didn't provide OS/product/release details so we're limited anyway.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Here is the result:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSRvduK9ZwqSQN_4bGTCCq_x5I6ATKyRyUY9D2MtCQD1XrQuuGo1oACs4RzLUVCrfbvFnYV2au8SrVW/pub

Comment: @guiverc I wasn't aware of those options until now

Comment: @guiverc 

Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Comment: Please add additional/corrected details (ie. your release details) to your question; any answers are written to your question itself; the *comments* being for us to ask you questions where your replies are done via additions/corrections to your actual question (*then comments get erased; answers are to question only as comments aren't permanent*)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem has been solved after running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

I cannot find any error message in the terminal output you have posted after running these commands.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I experienced freezes that lasted for several seconds when installing and reinstalling packages.

The issue got resolved after removing the `gnome-menus` package.